# Tiny MCE - вывод из редактора

Tags: javascript, php

Вопрос вот в чем, установил, настроил TinyMCE- теперь проблема состоит в том, как сделать так что-бы все что было в нем создано, в точности выводило и из базы на страницу? Т.е учитывались все bbcode...Кто сталкивался, помогите

Answer (score 1):

Ты выводишь данные из БД в (допустим ) **TEXTAREA** к которой подключен сам редактор и все.

Так же обратно любым из методов GET или POST лучше POST сохраняешь в БД.

Comment: это понятно, но если выводить обратно в textarea то пользователи смогут редачить данный текст, чего не хотелось бы, да и панель вверху будет не к стати! хотелось бы что-бы то что ты набрал в tiny выводилось отджельно и не зависимо учитывая все bbcode! Вот в этом проблема!

Comment: А это уже отдельно в PHP делаешь проверку текста и меняешь соответственно что тебе нужно.

Но вроде как тинимси все делает простыми HTML тегами по этому можно не запариваться на BB коды.

Comment: Shrek, вот тут надо химичить с проверкой. Что-бы никакая мышь не сунула было-код! Спс=)

Comment: пжлст. ну химичить не знаю, а ты для чего вообще с редактором мутишь? со стороны админки или просто на сайте чтобы комментить могли люди?

Comment: да сайт своей кафедре делаю, что-бы преподы смогли свои научные работы выкладывать, и не парились с копированием из word! Там замут много, так что я еще здесь с вопросами появлюсь =D

Comment: Ну тогда смысл париться с BB кодами?

В тинимси есть вставка из ворда, очистка стилей. Главное преподам покажи пару раз как оформлять текст в редакторе и всё. Счастье будет и тебе и им.